# Traps for table elements

Tags: snmp, mib, snmp-trap

In my MIB I have a table which contains properties for some entity. Herewith, once it is a table, there can be several entities of the same type. I also have a list of available traps, and there is a subset of traps, related to this entity type. But I don't see how can I determine which entity this trap is related to (first, second, ...). Is there I stated way to determine this, or my MIB is not complete?

Comment: The variables in the TRAP would be instances of the entity that the notification pertains to.

Comment: Please provide more information (like examples) to reveal what you are talking about.